# In Flutter, I'd like to call a for loop as soon as I navigate to a new screen. Where do I put the code?

Tags: dart, flutter

Basically I just want to call some code right away after pushing to a new screen. Where would I put my code?

Comment: Could you please add some code for reference that builds the 'new screen' widget? That would help everyone understand the situation easily and precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that in `build` method of your new screen widget.

Example from flutter.io:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {            
@override            
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 


 // instead of the next statement, place your code that you want to execute           
 final wordPair = WordPair.random();   



 return MaterialApp(            
   title: 'Welcome to Flutter',            
   home: Scaffold(            
       title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),            
     ),            
     body: Center(            
       child: Text('Hello World'),            
       child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase),            
     ),            
   ),            
 );
```

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question nicely.

Comment: No problem, happy coding :) and btw, I highly recommend going through flutter docs. I started learning flutter just last week, And what I do is follow docs from https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install. Basically keep reading until you have covered most of the basic concepts, and once you have covered basics - surf the net to meet your needs. And left hand side panel thing on flutter docs helps keep track of progress so nicely.